# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Subscription failed - no active Service Worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

I'm trying to subscribe the user but this is the error I get the first time.
The second time, it is working because the user is already active

This is my code :

```
 if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
   console.log('Service Worker is supported');
   navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function(reg) {
     console.log(':^)', reg);
     reg.pushManager.subscribe({
       userVisibleOnly: true
     }).then(function(sub) {
       console.log('endpoint:', sub.endpoint);
       var div = document.getElementById('id');
       div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + sub.endpoint;
       // var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
       //b.appendChild(div);
       //alert(sub.endpoint);
     });
   });
 }
```

I already tried the following, but the `ready.then()` method is not happening:

```
 if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
   console.log('Service Worker is supported');
   navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function(sreg) {
     console.log(':^)', sreg);
     navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(reg) {
       reg.pushManager.subscribe({
         userVisibleOnly: true
       }).then(function(sub) {
         console.log('endpoint:', sub.endpoint);
         var div = document.getElementById('id');
         div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + sub.endpoint;
         // var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
         //b.appendChild(div);
         //alert(sub.endpoint);
       });
     });
   });
 }
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 18):

You should wait for the service worker to be activated before triggering the subscription.

use stateChange listener for figuring out if service worker is active

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register(workerFileName, {scope: "/"})
    .then(
    function (reg) {
        var serviceWorker;
        if (reg.installing) {
            serviceWorker = reg.installing;
            // console.log('Service worker installing');
        } else if (reg.waiting) {
            serviceWorker = reg.waiting;
            // console.log('Service worker installed & waiting');
        } else if (reg.active) {
            serviceWorker = reg.active;
            // console.log('Service worker active');
        }

        if (serviceWorker) {
            console.log("sw current state", serviceWorker.state);
            if (serviceWorker.state == "activated") {
                //If push subscription wasnt done yet have to do here
                console.log("sw already activated - Do watever needed here");
            }
            serviceWorker.addEventListener("statechange", function(e) {
                console.log("sw statechange : ", e.target.state);
                if (e.target.state == "activated") {
                    // use pushManger for subscribing here.
                    console.log("Just now activated. now we can subscribe for push notification")
                    subscribeForPushNotification(reg);
                }
            });
        }
    },
    function (err) {
        console.error('unsuccessful registration with ', workerFileName, err);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can resolve this by checking for service worker status. Perform your actions only when the service worker is active.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js').then(function(reg) {
 if(reg.installing) {
        console.log('Service worker installing');
    } else if(reg.waiting) {
        console.log('Service worker installed');
    } else if(reg.active) {
        console.log('Service worker active');
    }
 // Include below mentioned validations
}
```

Check for pushnotification is supported or not using

```
 // Check if push messaging is supported  
    if (!('PushManager' in window)) {  
       console.log('Push messaging isn\'t supported.');  
       return;  
     }
   //
   if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {  
      console.log('The user has blocked notifications.');  
      return;  
   }
```

After these two checks implement you functionality.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(reg) {  .... })
```

Hope this helps

Comment: but its still not register the user, this is my problem

Comment: is this  console.log(':^)', reg); getting printed ?

Comment: Can you check if code without push manager is working fine or not ?

Comment: just comment out  reg.pushManager.subscribe({ code and check if it works fine ?

Comment: Try setting scope for serviceWorker.register method. Check my code @ https://github.com/bandhavya/bandhavya.github.io  I didnt include pushManager.

Comment: If i wasnt understood, i want to get the endpoint to register the user, and because the sw is not active yet, he give me this error